# Работа с командной строкой в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

У меня есть вот такой вот класс:

```
public class Solution {
    public static List<Person> allPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();
    static {
        allPeople.add(Person.createMale("Иванов Иван", new Date()));  //сегодня родился    id=0
        allPeople.add(Person.createMale("Петров Петр", new Date()));  //сегодня родился    id=1
    }

    private static Person getPerson(String name, String sex, String bd) throws ParseException {
        Person person = null;
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

        if(sex.equals("м")) person = Person.createMale(name, simpleDateFormat.parse(bd));
        else person = Person.createFemale(name, simpleDateFormat.parse(bd));
        return person;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        //start here - начни тут
        if (args[0].equals("-c")) {
            Person person = getPerson(args[1], args[2], args[3]);
            allPeople.add(person);
        } else if (args[0].equals("-u")) {
            Person person = getPerson(args[2], args[3], args[4]);
            int id = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
            allPeople.remove(id);
            allPeople.add(id, person);
        } else if (args[0].equals("-d")) {
            allPeople.remove(Integer.valueOf(args[1]));
        } else if (args[0].equals("-i")) {
            Person person = allPeople.get(Integer.valueOf(args[1]));
            System.out.println(person.getName() + " " + person.getSex() + " " + person.getBirthDay());
        }
    }
}
```

Моя программа на вход принимает аргументы из командной строки. Как запускать программу с аргументами в IntelliJ IDEA ? Не собирать же мне каждый раз jar для проверки....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run/Debug -> Edit Configuration
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]