# Как подать два параметра на вход метода main String args[]?

Tags: java, main

Первый - `path` - путь к директории, второй - `resultFileAbsolutePath` - имя (полный путь) существующего файла.

Comment: Если ответ помог вам, то примите его, нажав на стрелочку вверх рядом с ним и на галочку.

Answer (score 4):

В Java метод `main` принимает массив `String[] args`. `args` - это аргументы командной строки, которые вы можете указать при запуске.

Другими словами, если вы запустите свою программу из командной строки как `java MyProgram one two`, то `args` будет содержать `["one", "two"]`. Соответственно, вы можете запустить свою программу с нужными аргументами командной строки - `java MyProgram <path> <resultFileAbsolutePath>`.

[Источник(enSO).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java/890980#890980)

---

Если вы запускаете программу из IntelliJ, то вы можете указать аргументы в самой IDE. Для этого выполните шаги ниже:

В меню `Run/Debug` нажмите на `Edit Configuration`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В поле `Program arguments` введите аргументы командной строки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[Источник(ruSO).](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546451/218293)

---

[Аналогичная инструкция для Eclipse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373328/invoking-java-main-method-with-parameters-from-eclipse/374751#374751)

---

[Аналогичная инструкция для NetBeans.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168759/netbeans-how-to-set-command-line-arguments-in-java/9168863#9168863)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку

Comment: @MagometBahadirov пожалуйста. Не забудьте принять ответ ^^